# Issue: 0 Function Loaded: Azure Functions V2 (Blueprint) - Python - Referencing 'requests' library functions

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am working on an Azure Function - Python using V2 programming model.

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import requests

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.') 
    r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass', auth=('user', 'pass'))
    logging.info(r.status_code)

    name = req.params.get('name') 
    if not name: 
      try: 
          req_body = req.get_json() 
      except ValueError: 
         pass 
    else: 
        name = req_body.get('name') 

   if name: 
      return func.HttpResponse( 
        f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP-triggered function " 
        f"executed successfully.") 
   else: 
      return func.HttpResponse( 
         "This HTTP-triggered function executed successfully. " 
         "Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a" 
         " personalized response. New deployment 7", 
         status_code=200 
    )
```

When I deploy this function in Azure - I don't see the function within the function app.
**Error: 1 function found, 0 function loaded**

However, **if I remove the 'import requests' and it's related code - the function is visible in the function app.**

I tried putting that ('requests' related code) in the separate 'blueprint.py' file.  Referred this ([Azure Function V2 Python Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#blueprints) as well, still didn't work.

FYI: requirements.txt has the requests (referenced).

**How do I refer & use the library module function in Python V2 model? Is the blueprint necessary?**

Comment: The following app settings in the Azure Deploy task in the reelease pieline finally worked for me. Thanks for the support:    -ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD true -SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT true -AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags EnableWorkerIndexing   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies?tabs=linux#remote-build

Answer (score 0):

> **How do I refer & use the library module function in Python V2 model? Is the blueprint necessary?**

No, blueprint is not necessary to use requests library. I am able to publish the function successfully and can see the function in my function app as well.

**`Code`**

```
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  logging
import  requests

app  =  func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def  http_trigger1(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
r  =  requests.get('https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass', auth=('user', 'pass'))
logging.info(r.status_code)
name  =  req.params.get('name')
if  not  name:
try:
req_body  =  req.get_json()
except  ValueError:
pass
else:
name  =  req_body.get('name')
if  name:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
else:
return  func.HttpResponse(
"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
status_code=200
)
```

**`requirement.txt`**

```
azure-functions
requests
```

I debugged my function locally and it installed all the packages which are there in requirement.txt file.

[image]

Then I published my function as below and got the successfully published result.

[image]

[image]

I am able to see the function in my function app and also getting the expected output in `Code + Test` view.

[image]

[image]

**`References`**

[Make an Azure Function POST request in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275681/make-an-azure-function-post-request-in-python)

Comment: Thanks Afrin. But I am doing the deployment from Release Pipeline (Azure Functions Deploy Task - v2.0), Auto detect - deployment method. Is it necessary to package the requests modules in the .zip folder ? or Azure itself generates the package during runtime?

Comment: yes, Azure does not that automatically, you can try to deploy once using my way, check if its working for you.

Comment: Please check if you have `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags` in your function app configuration setting

Comment: Nope I do not have that AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags  setting, what should be the value ?

Comment: @SurajNaik value should be [this](https://i.imgur.com/5N77jyJ.png)

Comment: Try to set this value in the `Configuration` of function app and redeploy, hopefully it will work.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your deployment?

Comment: @SurajNaik how are you deploying your function now?

Comment: I am deploying it through Azure Release pipeline using the Azure Deploy task. Everything seems only. I am having issues with VS code deployment  3:29:16 PM func-ra624jmmvncrc: Starting deployment...
3:29:22 PM func-rafdfsdfsdncrc: Deleting setting "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"...
3:29:57 PM func-rafdfsdfsdncrc: Deploying Local Git repository to "func-rafdfsdfsdncrc"...
3:30:12 PM: Error: Failed to retrieve deployment status.

Comment: @SurajNaik can you share the code written for `Azure Functions Deploy Task - v2.0` Task in order to help you better, it seems to be something to do with this task. You can try to deploy directly from vs code , to see if its working

Comment: Here is the pipelines code:  steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Azure Function - Lock Link Deploy'
  inputs:
    connectedServiceNameARM: 'AZR-POC SPN'
    appType: functionAppLinux
    appName: 'func-rafdfsdfsdncrc'
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.7'

Comment: @SurajNaik can you share a screenshot? I would like to know how you are deploying? Are you following my deployment process?

Comment: The following app settings in the Azure Deploy task in the reelease pieline finally worked for me. Thanks for the support:    -ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD true -SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT true -AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags EnableWorkerIndexing   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies?tabs=linux#remote-build